# Differentiability in differential geometry

Tags: differential-geometry

Wikipedia offers a very straightforward definition of differentiability of a function
 $$f:\mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$$.
It also states that
 $$f:\mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$$ is differentiable at a point $$p$$ if all partial derivatives exist and are continuous in a neighborhood of $$p$$.
Now my question is, where can this definition and in particular the aforementioned condition be used for differentially of functions from a subset of $$\mathbb{R}^m$$ to
a subset of $$\mathbb{R}^n$$.
I'm asking this question because the DO CARMO book is defining differentiability of a function between two regular surfaces in a different way and at the same time is using the aforementioned condition literally anywhere before giving it it's own definition (while a regular surface is just a special kind of subset of $$\mathbb{R}^3$$).
I think it's being a little imprecise there and this confuses me in proofs.

Comment: You defined differentiability locally, so of course you can define it on open subsets, as opposed to the whole space.

Comment: This is all standard material in a rigorous treatment of multivariable calculus/analysis. You can look in analysis books, or you can, for example, check out some of my YouTube lectures, linked in my profile.